# Linking a servlet to a tab menu

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a question about `servlet/jsp/html`. I have a tab menu:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#list">LIST OF PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#add">ADD PRODUCT</a></li>
</ul>
  
<div class="tab-content">
   <div id="list" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>LIST OF PRODUCTS</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="add" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>ADD PRODUCT</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
```

I would like to link a `servlet` when I press a tab and consequently calling a jsp in the `tab-content`, instead of :

```
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

My `servlet` code :

```
@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
private BDBeanLocal bDBean;

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Products> list = new ArrayList<Products>();
        list =  bDBean.listaProdotti();

        request.setAttribute("lista", list);

        String arg = "/" + this.getServletName() + ".jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(arg);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);


    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

and this is my `web.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.NewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.loginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the hyperlink have a URL that you have a servlet mapping defined for in the `web.xml` file.

The `servlet-mapping` element defines a mapping between a servlet and a URL pattern. The example below maps the servlet named myservlet to any URL that starts with `/foo`:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.foo.examples.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/anything/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For this example, a hyperlink such as `<a href="/anything/test.html">Click Me</a>` would invoke the servlet.

by `url-pattern` you said every request after `/anything` should handled by **myservlet** `Servlet`. and after that you use something(test.html) after your `servlet` as your defined in `Servlet` `URL pattern` to **send a request** to `myservlet`.

**-----------**

Another way to call a servlet is using parameters.

```
<a href="servletUrl?param=value">click</a>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: the url pattern of my servlet is  <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>...I don't understand that test.html

Comment: I modified in this way : <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="/MyServlet">ADD PRODUCT</a></li> but I have error

Comment: i answered your question, also you can read more here : http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/ - goodluck!

Comment: Thank you so much , but my problems are opened :D

Comment: yw, and what is your problem ?! you can't call a servlet from a link without any url pattern !

Comment: just do what i said and you'll see your problem is solved! then you'll mark my answer as a correct answer! thanks.

Comment: I beg your pardon for the trouble. But <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="/NewServlet?param=value"> says me : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Comment: post your servlet code and web.xml in your question please

Comment: Done, now you can see servlet and web.xml

Comment: Ok, first put name = "/NewServlet" instead "NewServlet" in @WebServlet, then do something in your doGet method for example : request.getParameter("parameterName"); - Goodluck!

Comment: I think that's wrong.. 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [NewServlet] and Servlet [/NewServlet] have the same url pattern: [/NewServlet]

Comment: remove servlet mapping in your xml or @webServlet to fix this error! print something in doGet method, now the result?

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: NewServlet?param=value

Comment: what about localhost:8080/NewServlet ?

Comment: Ok it works in this way : localhost:8080/NewServlet.do?param=value. I tried to insert this in the href <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="/NewServlet.do?param=value">Add product </a></li> and when I click this tab doesn't work.

Comment: what about if you put /NewServlet/* instead /NewServlet in your web.xml url pattern and href="/NewServlet.do/?param=value" ?